# Django different authentication for different URLs

Tags: django

I have two Django apps called `frontend` and `affiliates` like so:

```
django/
    manage.py
    frontend/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
    affiliate/
        __init__.py
        models.py
        views.py
```

I want people to be able to have two accounts, they sign up for their frontend account at `domain.com/signup/` and their affiliate account at `domain.com/affilate/signup/`.

I've got no problem with sorting that out, but is it possible to have them logged into both accounts at the same time? If they visit and page on `domain.com` they are authenticated with their frontend account, and if they visit any page on `domain.com/affiliate/` they are authenticated on their affiliate account.

I have models for the accounts that look like this:

```
class Account(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, db_index=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

For frontend.

```
class Affiliate(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, db_index=True)
    username = models.CharField(max_length=32, db_index=True, unique=True)
    password = models.CharField(max_length=32)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=128, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

For affiliates.

Is it possible to have two different sets of django users so the `user = models.OneToOneField(User, db_index=True)` field relates to a different set of users for the frontend account than the affiliate accounts? Because I want people to be able to use the same usernames for both accounts. If they're both dipping into the same pool of django users I will get duplicate username errors. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of a `OneToOne` between the `User` model and the custom profile models, you could have a `ForeignKey` to the `User` instead. Then in the `Account` views, you could have the check `if hasattr(user, 'account')` and in the `Affiliate` views, `if hasattr(user, 'affiliate`).

Just make sure you don't allow more than one of each type of profile for each user object. You could do that either in the view, or the model. I'd say do it in both places.

Answer (score 0):

Based on what you've told us, I'd say: create one model `Account` for frontend users and use a `ForeignKey` to associate that model to an `Affiliate` model if needed.

That way, everyone's logging in with the same user accounts and you can lookup affiliate information for a user by accessing the `Affiliate` model.